# Create Function in h2 from Oracle

Tags: java, database, oracle, function, h2

i have the following function in oracle that i have to translate into h2. Could anyone help me. I have no idea to do this:

```
create or replace function unpack_info (p_trackchar table.ordchar%type) 
 return varchar2 is
l_res varchar2(8);
begin
select decode(bitand(to_number(ascii(p_trackchar)),1),1,'1','0') ||
  decode(bitand(to_number(ascii(p_trackchar)),2),2,'1','0') ||
  decode(bitand(to_number(ascii(p_trackchar)),4),4,'1','0') ||
  decode(bitand(to_number(ascii(p_trackchar)),8),8,'1','0') ||
  decode(bitand(to_number(ascii(p_trackchar)),16),16,'1','0') ||
  decode(bitand(to_number(ascii(p_trackchar)),32),32,'1','0') ||
  decode(bitand(to_number(ascii(p_trackchar)),64),64,'1','0') into l_res
from dual;
return l_res;
end;
```

I have tried to do first some basics but the creation of this function will not work:

```
CREATE ALIAS HTS.TEST AS $$
String nextPrime(String value){
 return null;
}
$$;
```

I get this error:

> Error: Syntax Fehler in SQL Befehl "CREATE ALIAS HTS.TEST AS [*]$$
>       String nextPrime(String value){
>       return null"
>       Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE ALIAS HTS.TEST AS [*]$$
>       String nextPrime(String value){
>       return null" [42000-162]

Is this the right way to do the translation or what can i do?

I have created an alias (the test one) and could execute it. Now O have to create the alias for unpack:info. Could someone help me cause of the syntax etc. how does the function looks as an alias in h2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem. How exactly did you run the statement? Possibly you run the statement with a tool that only sent part of the query? Or possibly there is a 'special character' (some kind of unicode space) just before the '$$'?  I tried this:

```
create schema hts;
CREATE ALIAS HTS.TEST AS $$
String nextPrime(String value){
    return null;
}
$$;
```

Could you try this again in the H2 Console?

Comment: +1 It's odd that the error message doesn't contain the last `}` + `$$`.

Comment: The reason for that is: the H2 database engine didn't actually get the complete statement, it only got it up to the first semicolon (after the 'null'). Why this occurred I don't know, I think it's related to the tool that run the script.

Comment: I agree. The tool probably configured to split queries at `;` to make it behave with databases like Oracle which use `;` to terminate statements. @bladepit: Check the settings of your tool.

Comment: ok i used squirresql...but with the h2 console it works. now i have create an function but how could i use this function in an sql?

Answer (score 10):

Use ' as the escaped sequence instead of $$. In between if you want to use the escape sequence use $$. so the code would look like:

```
CREATE ALIAS HTS.TEST AS '
public static String nextPrime(String value){
 return null;
}
';
```

Comment: I think you don't need to include the `public static` since I was getting an error about a repeat modifier.

Comment: `public static` must be absent in method declaration, see [how template is used to create a complete Java class](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions).

Answer (score 1):

This should work but the syntax error suggests that your version of H2 doesn't support this. Are you using the latest version?

If not, it's a bug. File it.

As a workaround, write the function in Java, compile it to a JAR, add the JAR to the classpath and use it with `CREATE ALIAS HTS.TEST FOR "...package.Type...";`

See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions for an example.

Comment: jeah im am using version 1.3.162 the latest version on the website. i dont unterstand what you mean in the last part of your post. should i simple create an class with the function and then add it to the classpath?

Comment: Yes. See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions for an example.